# Is there a way to reference environment variables for an npm package from a consumer app?

Tags: build, environment-variables, svelte, sveltekit, npm-package

I am creating a package on npm and for simplicity reasons I am trying to use environment variables in my npm package ( since user secret is needed ) that would be defined by a consumer app. But I seem to run into build issues when using the created package.

The structure looks something like this:

```
My demo app
|
|-----My npm package
|
|-----Other packages for my demo app
...
```

I have my `npm package` ( on npm ) and a `demo app` to showcase how the `package` works. I have environment variables used in the `package`, but I want to define them in my `demo app`.

In my `package` I am referencing the environment variables as such:

```
// My package
// auth-config.js

const config = {
    variable1: import.meta.env['PUBLIC_VITE_VARIABLE_1'],
    variable2: import.meta.env['PUBLIC_VITE_VARIABLE_2'],
    variable3: import.meta.env['PUBLIC_VITE_VARIABLE_3']
};

export default config;
```

And later using them in my `package` code:

```
// My package 
// auth-service.ts

const user = await getUser({
    variable1: config.variable1,
    variable2: config.variable2,
    variable3: config.variable3
});
```

Then I have them defined in my `demo app`:

```
// Demo app 
// .env

PUBLIC_VITE_VARIABLE_1=some-value
PUBLIC_VITE_VARIABLE_2=some-value-2
PUBLIC_VITE_VARIABLE_3=some-value-3
```

Then, when building ( `npm run build` ) my `demo application`, I am getting the following errors:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'PUBLIC_VITE_VARIABLE_1')
    at file:///C:/Users/user1/Namu/login-with-auth/node_modules/my-app/auth0/auth-config.js:2:28
```

However, the dev build works completely fine. And it uses the variables successfully as well.

My configuration for both the `package` and the `demo app` is:

- Svelte + Svelte Kit
- Vite
- Typescript

I have tried using different approaches to import environment variables ( `process.env` instead of `import.meta.env` ) inside the package. I have also tried updating the `svelte.config.js` and `vite.config.js` with different paths to environment variables to try and reach the scope of the application that uses this package.

I am not sure where to go from here, since I can't find any definitive answer online and nothing seems to work so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue in the end. Keep in mind I am using `svelte` + `svelte-kit` + `vite` in both the `package` and the `demo app` using the `package`.

The fix goes like this:

1. Name the environment variables properly. Naming convention should follow what the bundler says, not what the framework says. In my case for `vite` it has to start with `VITE_`, so the environment variable would be `VITE_VARIABLE_1`. More info can be found [Here](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html).

   *Side note: this is also configurable, but I could not make the configurations work in my favour.*
2. Using proper references in the package. For vite, the correct way to reference an env variable is by using `import.meta.env['VITE_VARIABLE_1']`.
3. Adding checks for undefined when using the variables in the package like so: 
    `import.meta.env ? import.meta.env['VITE_VARIABLE_1'] : ''`. 
   This let's you avoid the build errors that I was running into, since at build time, `import.meta.env` is not defined.

And this is how the final files look like:

Where the environment variables are **referenced**:

```
// My package
// auth-config.js

const variable1 = import.meta.env ? import.meta.env['PUBLIC_VITE_VARIABLE_1'] : '';
const variable2 = import.meta.env ? import.meta.env['PUBLIC_VITE_VARIABLE_2'] : '';
const variable3 = import.meta.env ? import.meta.env['PUBLIC_VITE_VARIABLE_3'] : '';

const config = {
    variable1,
    variable2,
    variable3
};
```

Where the environment variables are **used**:

```
// My package 
// auth-service.ts

const user = await getUser({
    variable1: config.variable1,
    variable2: config.variable2,
    variable3: config.variable3
});
```

Where the environment variables are **defined**:

```
// Demo app 
// .env

PUBLIC_VITE_VARIABLE_1=some-value
PUBLIC_VITE_VARIABLE_2=some-value-2
PUBLIC_VITE_VARIABLE_3=some-value-3
```

You can also look at the insides of the created [Package](https://github.com/Golemas7/sveltekit-auth0/blob/main/src/lib/auth0/auth-config.ts).
And the coresponding files: [auth-config.js](https://github.com/Golemas7/sveltekit-auth0/blob/main/src/lib/auth0/auth-config.ts), [auth-service.ts](https://github.com/Golemas7/sveltekit-auth0/blob/main/src/lib/auth0/auth-service.ts).